# Pack file to user Dekstop from deb archive

Tags: linux, deb, dpkg

Is there a way to set the unpacking destination a single file to user Desktop folder?
To set Something like home\$user\Desktop structure in the package folder.
I know I can set unpacking directory with --root option for the whole package, but I need only part of the archive to be unpacked to the Desktop

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a postinst script. Check out the debian website for details:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/HowTo/DistributeFilesToUserDesktops

If your not bothered about having a desktop icon; then I would recommend that you create a path for the launcher. Normal launchers are really .desktop files in /usr/share/applications/